# Select the majority value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A                         B                 C                  D     
1                            Sales Price      Sales Price         Sales Price
2                              January           February            March
3    Year 01                      50                70                 90
4    Year 02                      50                60                 40
5    Year 03                      60                70                 30
6    Year 04                      40                60                 50
7    Year 05                      50                40                 25
8
9    Majority Sales Price:        50                70                 90
```

In **Rows 3-7** you see the sales price of a product from the months `January-March` in 5 years (`Year 01 - Year 05`).

In **Row 9** I want to select the sales price which has the **majority** within each month. 
For example in `January` the **sales price** of `50` has the majority because it appears both in `Year 01` and `Year 02`.

Please keep in mind the following criterias:

a) If there is no majority of a sales price the highest sales price should be picked. *(**Cell D9**)* 
b) If two or more sales prices have the same majority the higher one should be picked. *(**Cell C9**)*

What formula do I need to get my desired result?

Comment: Do you only deal with positive values? Or is it possible that the formula would ever return a negative value?

Comment: Negative values might also be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell B9 enter the following formula as an array, i.e. Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
{=IFERROR(MAX(MODE.MULT(B3:B7)), MAX(B3:B7))}
```

This uses `MODE.MULT` to find the modal value(s), which returns the result as an array. If there is more than one modal value, `MAX` returns the highest out of that array. If there is no modal value, `MODE.MULT` throws an error, hence the `IFERROR` statement which is used to find the max value in the error case.

Comment: Great solution. I was working on something with `SUMPRODUCT` but this is much more elegant. Never knew of the `MODE.MULT` function until now.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I actually do not need the Ctrl+Shift+Enter. It seems to work without the array as well or is there something I should consider?

Comment: @Michi, MODE.MULT returns an array of values so should require the formula to be entered as an array, i.e. with the {}. However I have just tried it without the {} and still got the same result... In short, I don't know. I'd include it as an array formula to avoid any unexpected results.

Comment: Just figured out the difference. The array formula is only necessary if I want to display ALL values in case there are values with the same majority. In my example above this would apply to Column C because the 60 and the 70 have the same majority. I would have to insert the array formula in Cell C9 and Cell C10 to display both values. However, due to the critiera b) in my question I do not want to display both values. I only want to show the highest one. Therefore, the MODE.MULT function without array combined with the MAX function gives back the correct result.