# Create a list of majority values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
            A                     B   
    1    Values         Descending order of majority values
    2      50                     80 (--> Appears 6 times in Column A)
    3      80                    -10 (--> Appears 6 times in Column A)
    4     -10                     50 (--> Appears 3 times in Column A)
    5     -10                     70 (--> Appears 1 time in Column A)
    6     -10                     40 (--> Appears 1 time in Column A)
    7      40 
    8      80                 
    9     -10   
   10      80
   11     -10   
   12      50
   13      80
   14      50
   15      70
   16      80
   17      80
   18     -10
   19
```

In `Column A` I have a list of values. 
In `Column B` I want to list the values based on their majority in the list.

The only formla I could find so far is the one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057201/select-the-majority-value):

```
={MAX(MODE.MULT(A1:A18))}
```

This formula would give me the value with the highest majority which is in this case `80` but I cannot create a list out of it.

Do you have any idea of a formula that could create such a list?

---

**NOTE:**

a) Values in `Column A` can have the same majority. If this is the case I want that both values are listed in `Column B` (In this case `80` and `-10`)

b) Values in `Column A` can be positive or negative.

Comment: Did you try something like this [Find the top 10 values in an Excel range without sorting](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/find-the-top-10-values-in-an-excel-range-without-sorting/)?

Comment: A [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) is probably the easiest.

Comment: @PEH: My question is not a duplicate of the one you mentioned! In the question you mentioned a list of the MAX-values should be created. My question is about the MAJORITY-value which means that my question is about how OFTEN a value appears in the list and not how HIGH the value itself is!

Comment: Another resource you would find at Google: [List most frequently occuring numbers](https://exceljet.net/formula/list-most-frequently-occuring-numbers)

Comment: @Michi if you are after "how often" then you should check out the frequency() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this array formula in the first cell and drag down:

```
=LARGE(IF(FREQUENCY($A$2:$A$18,$A$2:$A$18)=LARGE(FREQUENCY($A$2:$A$18,$A$2:$A$18),ROW(1:1)),$A$2:$A$18),SUMPRODUCT(--(LARGE(FREQUENCY($A$2:$A$18,$A$2:$A$18),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW(1:1))))=LARGE(FREQUENCY($A$2:$A$18,$A$2:$A$18),ROW(1:1)))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit Mode

[image]